# Why is my Python 3 code compiling itself?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.3, compiled

I was following the Python 3 Docs to learn Multiprocessing, but I noticed something strange that I hadn't noticed before. After running the script the code is then compiled into a working standalone binary in a "**pycache**" directory. Can somebody please explain this to me? 
I am using Windows 8 and Python 3.3 if it matters (AMD64 for both). Thank you.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello',name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
        p.join()
    input() #Added this so that I can see my results.
```

Tutorial I was following:
http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a module is imported, Python will cache the bytecode so it doesn't need to reparse the file. The cached bytecode goes in a `__pycache__` folder. `multiprocessing` implicitly imports your module, so it is cached. It can be safely ignored, as Python is smart and will not use it if it is out of date. If you *really* don't want it to be making those directories and files everywhere, set the environment variable `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` to `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Short and simple answer :)